# AWS Glue ApplyMapping from double to string

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I'm having a bit of a frustrating issues with a Glue Job.

I have a table which I have created from a crawler.  It's gone through some CSV data and created a schema.  Some elements of the schema need to be modified, e.g. numbers to strings and apply a header.

I seem to be running into some problems here - the schema for some fields appears to be have picked up as a double.  When I try and convert this into a string which is what I require, it includes some empty precision e.g. 1234 --> 1234.0.

The mapping code I have is something like:

```py
applymapping1 = ApplyMapping.apply(
    frame = datasource0, 
    mappings = [
        ("col1","double","first_column_name","string"),
        ("col2","double","second_column_name","string")
    ], 
    transformation_ctx = "applymapping1"
 )
```

And the resulting table I get after I've crawled the data is something like:

```
first_column_name    second_column_name
1234.0               4321.0
5678.0               8765.0
```

as opposed to

```
first_column_name    second_column_name
1234                 4321
5678                 8765
```

Is there a good way to work around this?  I've tried changing the schema in the table that is initially created by the crawler to a bigint as opposed to a double, but when I update the mapping code to     ("col1","bigint","first_column_name","string") the table just ends up being null.

Comment: You may want to convert your dynamicframe to a spark dataframe, then use String manipulation to remove the last two characters?

Answer (score 5):

Just a little correction from botchniaque answer, you actually have to do BOTH ResolveChoice and then ApplyMapping to ensure the correct type conversion.

ResolveChoice will make sure you just have one type in your column. If you do not make this step and the ambiguity is not resolved, the column will become a struct and Redshift will show this as null in the end.

So apply ResolveChoice to make sure all your data is one type (int, for ie)

`df2 = ResolveChoice.apply(datasource0, specs = [("col1", "cast:int"), ("col2", "cast:int")])`

Finally, use ApplyMapping to change type for what you want

```
df3 = ApplyMapping.apply(
frame = df2, 
mappings = [
    ("col1","int","first_column_name","string"),
    ("col2","int","second_column_name","string")
], 
transformation_ctx = "applymapping1")
```

Hope this helps (:

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your data is really of type double (some values may have a fractions), and that's why changing type results in data being turned to null. Also it's no wonder that when you change type of a `double` field to `string` it gets serialized with a decimal component - it's still a double, just printed.

Have you tried explicitly casting the values to integer?

```
df2 = ResolveChoice.apply(datasource0, specs = [("col1", "cast:int"), ("col2", "cast:int")])
```

And then to case to string

```
df3 = ResolveChoice.apply(df2, specs = [("col1", "cast:string"), ("col2", "cast:string")])
```

or use `ApplyMapping` to change type and rename as you did above.

```
df3 = ApplyMapping.apply(
frame = df2, 
mappings = [
    ("col1","int","first_column_name","string"),
    ("col2","int","second_column_name","string")
], 
transformation_ctx = "applymapping1"
```

)

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. The glue script that was auto-generated used ApplyMapping to change the type just like your above solution. But the whole column became null in my parquet output